# How to generate multiple series from column entries, grouped by another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, series, transformation

I have a table similar to this one:

| name | total_hours_played |
| --- | --- |
| George | 2 |
| Martina | 5 |

From which I want to generate a table such as this one:

| name | hours_played_through |
| --- | --- |
| George | 1 |
| George | 2 |
| Martina | 1 |
| Martina | 2 |
| Martina | 3 |
| Martina | 4 |
| Martina | 5 |

Each entry in the first table translates to a series in the second that goes up until the number in 'total_hours_played' and is grouped by 'name'. How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I did the following (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=648bae4f713db1807f8b53b09b73800b)):

```
CREATE TABLE total_hours_played
(
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  hpt  SMALLINT NOT NULL
);
```

populate it:

```
INSERT INTO total_hours_played VALUES
('George', 2),
('Martina', 5);
```

Then run this SQL:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
  SELECT name, 1 AS x FROM total_hours_played
    UNION ALL
  SELECT name, x + 1 FROM cte
  WHERE x < 
    (SELECT MAX(hpt) FROM total_hours_played 
       WHERE name = (SELECT name FROM total_hours_played WHERE name = cte.name))
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY name, x;
```

Result:

```
name        x
George      1
George      2
Martina     1
Martina     2
Martina     3
Martina     4
Martina     5
```

Et voilà!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate_series on each row of input for that row. (see demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=01d4bf6ecf5ed0d4ac009aba1ce6aaa5))

```
with test (name, hours_played)  as
     ( values ('George',2)
            , ('Martina', 5)
     ) 
 -- your query starts here
select name 
     , generate_series(1, hours_played)  
 from test;
```